# What happens when I do: queryset.anything = 'something'?

Tags: python, django, variables, django-queryset

I did this thing:

```
>>> latest.values('amount')
<QuerySet [{'amount': 100}, {'amount': 100}, {'amount': 100}, {'amount': 180}]>
>>> latest.values('amount').total=480
>>> latest.values('amount').total
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'total'
>>>
```

Is there any way to use `latest.values('amount').total`?

Is it possible to add something in a queryset?

> Edit:

I have expected that now I would be able to find `total` in `qs` . How did `total` add?

```
>>> qs = latest.values('amount')
>>> qs.total = 480
>>> qs.total
480
>>> qs
<QuerySet [{'amount': 100}, {'amount': 100}, {'amount': 100}, {'amount': 180}]> #why there is no 'total' ?
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`latest.values` returns a new object every time you call it. When you assigned `total` to the otherwise anonymous `QuerySet` instance, the attribute was created, but the object is immediately garbage collected as there is no reference to it. The next call returns a *new* object that has no `total` attribute.

You need to save a reference to that specific object if you want to retain a non-standard attribute.

```
>>> qs = latest.values('amount')
>>> qs.total = 480
>>> qs.total
480
```

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about the class `QuerySet` here. You can add attributes to instance of most classes simply by assignment. That doesn't mean, though, that `QuerySet.__repr__` will take such attributes into account.